# Invalid attempt to call MetaData when reader is closed

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I want to store some values in my database based on if the user email exists in my table or not.

This is the code:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=SAMA-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=advCenter;Integrated Security=True");
        int str = 0;
        SqlCommand com2 = new SqlCommand("select [user_Account] from [User] where [user_Email]=@s", con);
        com2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@s", Convert.ToString(Session["mail"]));
        SqlDataReader rd;
        con.Open();
        rd = com2.ExecuteReader();
        if (rd.HasRows)
        {
                con.Close();
                con.Open();
                str = Convert.ToInt32(rd["user_Account"]);
                str = str + 30;
                SqlCommand co = new SqlCommand("update [User] set [user_Account]=@ua WHERE [user_Email]=@em", con);
                co.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ua", str);
                co.Parameters.AddWithValue("@em", Convert.ToString(Session["mail"]));
                co.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
        }
        else
        {
            SqlCommand c = new SqlCommand("insert into [User] values(@e,@s,@a)", con);
            c.Parameters.AddWithValue("@e", Session["mail"].ToString());
            c.Parameters.AddWithValue("@s", "logged in");
            c.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a", "30");
            con.Open();
            c.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
        }
```

but while running the code I get the error `Invalid attempt to call MetaData when reader is closed.` at this line:

```
str = Convert.ToInt32(rd["user_Account"]);
```

What can i do to solve it? I tried more and more in `con.open()` and `con.close()` but each  time I get the error saying that `reader` is closed or that `reader` associated whith line that is closed too.

Answer (score 1):

You should not close the connection *at all* until you've finished using it. It should remain open until you've completely finished with it.

You should also, in this code, only open it *once*.

And you should be using `rd.Read()` rather than `HasRows`. The reader is not "filled" until then.

Check out the sample in the [SqlDataReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.aspx) documentation, your code needs to conform to that sequence of calls.

Comment: well i do this but con.open() after connection definition and close it at the end but i get this error :Invalid attempt to read when no data is present. at: str = Convert.ToInt32(rd["user_Account"]);??????????????????????

Comment: May be this is another error. You may need calling rd.Read() before reading from datareader.

Comment: @semsema: updated my answer. please read the sample in the docs linked.

Comment: i use rd.read() and edit my open and closed connectio but still have this error:There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first.at this line :Line 66:             co.ExecuteNonQuery();
??????

Answer (score 1):

use the using statement. it will close your connection at the closing brace.

```
using ( SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=SAMA-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=advCenter;Integrated Security=True") )
{
    con.Open();

    // do work here...

    rd = com2.ExecuteReader();
    // use Read instead of HasRows. this will give false, if there is no data
    if (rd.Read())
    {
         //...
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`con.Close(); con.Open();` should not be there.  Remove these after your if statement.  You are closing off the connection and then re-opening it causing all your data to be lost.

Just use the same connection, create a new `SQLCommand`, and run that on a new reader.  That should allow you to accomplish what it seems you are trying to do.

Cheers.